# при запуске vsCode на убунте появляется значок в панели, но само окно программы не отображается

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

при запуске vsCode  на убунте появляется значок в панели, но само окно программы не отображается

Comment: Запустите в терминале `code --verbose` и посмотрите, что пишет в логах.

Comment: пробуй с отключением аппаратного ускорения.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй с выключенным аппаратным видео ускорением

```
code --disable-gpu
```

Если заработает - проверяй дрова на видео.